# Retain cycle between 3 variables set up in a circle?

Tags: ios, swift

In my app I have a set of classes connected like this ->

```
class1.delegate = class2
class2.delegate = class3
class3.delegate = class1
```

Would this cause a retain cycle? The delegates are protocols of which the classes conform to.

```
var delegate: protocol!
```

`class1` conforms to `UIViewController` as well.

It seems like when I don't assign `class2` as a `delegate` (comment out `class1.delegate = class2`), `class1` can `deinit` when popped. When I comment out lines that do `class1.delegate.func()`, `class1` still can't `deinit` when popped.

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BZjQu.png) This is a partial picture of one of the classes in the memory graph. They all look like this.

Comment: Yep, this causes a retain cycle.

Comment: Delegates should always be `weak`. Use `weak var delegate: protocol?`.

Comment: See also [the Delegation section in the Swift Programming Language](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/Protocols.html#ID276): "To prevent strong reference cycles, delegates are declared as weak references."

Comment: It would have been easy to answer this question yourself just by trying it. Also, if you're in doubt, use the Leaks instrument or the graphical memory debugger.

Comment: @matt, I have noticed the retain cycle because there is no deinit. After extensive searching however, I always only find mention of two variables having strong vars to eachother causing retain cycles but not a larger circle like this.

Comment: Ultimately, question why your logic is designed this way in the first place, too.  Indirectly, you're basically saying that class1 and class2 are each other's delegates to a degree.

Comment: @tswift any time there's a strong ref to an instance, that instance will be retained.  The size of the chain of strong references doesn't affect anything.  In fact, a single object could create a retain cycle by having a strong reference to itself.  You'll see this a lot in objects that have closures with non-weakified references to self.

Comment: @kid_x, thank you! I'll have to figure out how to assign these delegates without them becoming nil instantly. It seems like since there's only 1 ref to the classes, and they'll go nil immediately due to ARC of 0.

Comment: Have a look at that link @DavidRönnqvist posted.  Delegates aren't really meant to be used for ownership purposes, but rather, just for delegation.

Comment: "I have noticed the retain cycle because there is no deinit." Excellent, so you've answered your own question. If you were in doubt about whether this was caused by a retain cycle, you could easily have used Instruments or the memory grapher, as I said before. As for your research, it's just faulty; sure, people usually use a two-instance cycle to illustrate, but that's just an example.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, this will cause a strong reference cycle. It doesn’t matter how many objects are involved in the cycle, it’s still a cycle.

Run the app in the debugger and click on the “debug memory graph” button, [image], and you will see the strong reference cycle visually:

[image]

Note not only the circular set of references in the main panel, but also the exclamation marks in the navigator panel on the left.

To fix this, your `delegate` references should be `weak`:

```
weak var delegate: FooDelegate?
```

And, FYI, if you do that, you may want to therefore define your protocol to be a [class-only protocol](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/Protocols.html#ID281), e.g.:

```
protocol FooDelegate: AnyObject {
    ...
}
```

---

You said:

> When I comment out lines that do `class1.delegate.func()`, `class1` still can't `deinit` when popped.

Yes, the strong reference cycle has nothing to do with whether you actually invoked any of the protocols methods, but merely whether you have a circular set of strong references.

Comment: I actually did open this up and it doesn't show a circular set of references or exclamation marks and that was confusing me. I have attached a picture to the post.

Comment: You will only see the exclamation marks when the strong reference cycle when there are no other references to those objects in question. E.g. if your view controller participates in the strong reference cycle, you have to dismiss the view controller first before “debug memory graph” can determine that there is a cycle.

Comment: I called pop on the viewController and it went away before pulling up the graph and it showed the above image.

Comment: If you pop the view controller and then tap on the “debug memory graph” button and the view controller instance is not shown in the panel on the left, then it’s obviously not participating in a strong reference cycle.

Comment: Sorry, I meant the viewController did disappear from the screen. When I pull up the graph, it shows it still in memory with the above image.

Comment: If you pop, the “debug memory graph” gets confused by the navigation controller. If the view in question was not pushed/popped, but rather presented/dismissed, then you’ll see the above memory graph. But regardless, a circular set of strong references _will_ result in strong reference cycle unless you break that cycle (e.g. with `weak` references).